# Java convert String[] to int[]

Tags: java, collections

I have a String[], where each element is convertible to an integer.  What's the best way I can convert this to an int[]?

```
int[] StringArrayToIntArray(String[] s)
{
    ... ? ...
}
```

Comment: Looks an awful lot like homework, apologies if it is not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static int[] StringArrToIntArr(String[] s) {
   int[] result = new int[s.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      result[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Simply iterate through the string array and convert each element.

*Note:*  If any of your elements fail to parse to an `int` this method will throw an exception.  To keep that from happening each call to `Integer.parseInt()` should be placed in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: don't forget the try/catch block

Comment: @Woot, the asker specified that each element is convertible to an `int` so I intentionally omitted it.

Comment: You have a } in place of a { at the start of the for loop.

Answer (score 13):

Now that Java's finally caught up to functional programming, there's a better answer:

```
int[] StringArrayToIntArray(String[] stringArray)
{
    return Stream.of(stringArray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html):

```
return Ints.toArray(Collections2.transform(Arrays.asList(s), new Function<String, Integer>() {
    public Integer apply(String input) {
        return Integer.valueOf(input);
    }
});
```

Admittedly this isn't the cleanest use ever, but since the `Function` could be elsewhere declared it might still be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to convert a String to an Int.

```java
    String str = "15";
    int i;
    
    i = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Here is an example were you to do some math with an User's input:

```java
    int i;
    String input;
    i = Integer.parseInt(str);
    input = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Give me a number, and I'll multiply with 2");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number is: " + i * 2);
```

Output:

Popup: A dialog with an input box that says: Give me a number, and I'll multiply it with 2.

Popup: The number is: inputNumber * 2

Answer (score 1):

convert String[] to Integer[] in java 8:

```
Integer[] myArray = Stream.of(new String[] { "1", "2", "3" })
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```